# Netbeans - importing project

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I developed a java swing project and it worked fine when i compile and run it in my pc.  But it does not run properly when i copy the project folder and open it in another pc.  It runs but it does not acces the other classes in the package.  Only the main class gets executed.  But the output JAR works fine in both PCs.  Can anyone tell me what might have went wrong?

Comment: What versions of Netbeans are installed on those 2 PCs ? Are the same versions of JDK available on the 2 PCs ?

Comment: Both have the same version and the same JDK.. !!

Comment: What error(s) do you get ? Are you sure you're not forgetting to copy some JAR that the project is dependent on ? Are you sure the project doesn't rely on some specific environment variables which are only present on one of the systems ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy the ***entire*** folder for the project.